# an iOS app for my classifieds ads website

Tags: ios, ads

Im into learning swift2 using Xcode 7 and I want to even create an iOS app for my classifieds ads website! I am not a good programmer but I do believe that I can make it by myself if only someone can give me tips on which way to connect Data from the site into the app! Should i have separated database or I can relay on the contents on my website to be transferred to the app! If there any way to do that please let me know! I apprecaite  it !

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways that you can go about accomplishing what you need to do. You could create a link to your website using

```
var url = NSURL(String:"Your website address")
if url != nil {
let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!, completionHandler.{(data, response, error) ->void in 
if error != nil {
//Handle error
} else {
//what you would like to do
}}
```

You could go about creating a table with the cells having links to that particular item on your website. How you implement it is up to you. You can also look into creating an online db using any cloud service and link it to your app.

Comment: Ver useful , thanks a lot Jobs. But what about JSON data!

Comment: JSON data comes in when you configure a database on the cloud. You can serialize the JSON data that you fetch in your app using :
NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData{ data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as NSDictionary